# Apache Chemistry CMIS session.createDocument vs folder.createDocument

Tags: cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I would like someone to give me the difference between the session createDocument and folder createDocument methods.

Also within this context is there a sample on how I could use document appendContentStream() method, I was struggling to see an example online, I have a requirement where documents sizes can be up to 300-350MB and I was keen to know more about the appendContentStream() after it was recommended at the Nuxeo webinar by Jeff Potts though he did mention size around 1GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Session.createDocument()` creates a document and returns the document ID. `Folder.createDocument()` creates a document and returns a complete Document object. To do that, `Folder.createDocument()` needs one more round-trip to the server. If you just want to create a document and you are not interested in the document properties, or the document permissions, or the document renditions, etc., use the Session variant. It's faster.

The CMIS specification does not limit the document size. Some repositories support uploading a document of several GBs in one go. If such an upload fails, for example if there is a connection problem, you have to repeat the complete upload, though. `appendContentStream()` allows uploading a document in chunks. If uploading a chunk fails, you only have to repeat the upload of that one chunk. If that makes sense depends on your application, your repository, and your network.

There is a `appendContentStream()` code example (maybe not a good one) in the OpenCMIS TCK:
https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-test/chemistry-opencmis-test-tck/src/main/java/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/tck/tests/crud/SetAndDeleteContentTest.java?view=markup